# Design for recording and transmitting audio from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, audio, android-mediarecorder

I have two Android devices (Phone A & Phone B) and a server with a MySQL database. I want to send an audio message using a microphone, from Phone A to Phone B, through the server.

One idea is to:

- use the microphone from the Phone A
- record audio to a file in SD card
- get bytes of this file and send to server as a simple text message
- the server stores this data in the database
- Phone B will poll server and receive this data
- then write the bytes to a new file
- then play it with MediaPlayer

  1. Is this correct?
  2. Does bytes have special characters ?

Comment: Not an Android dev, but: I would probably record this on the SD Card, yes. I would expect you don't _have_ to, but it would be better to write to a local reliable medium, so if your internet connection fails, it will record fine and it can be sent when the connection comes back. Also, RAM can quickly fill up with media recording on mobile devices, and you risk a buffer overflow if your connection won't drain the buffer as fast as you are recording.

Answer (score 1):

you need to capture the audio on phone A, and send it as binary data to the server. You can use a simple POST request to do so.

The server should store that to a file, not the database -- the database should only contain the filename and path, plus an id.

Phone B polls / gets push notification about the file. Server uses ID to get filename from database and uses `passthru` to serve the file.

Comment: but the Problem here , is that Anyone who copy/paste MyUrl.com/Audio will have access to the Records , if i set Permission to 666 ?

Comment: yes, anyone who can "guess" the url can have haccess. but that's why you typically would use something hard, similar to the way bit.ly uses hashes. filesystem permissions are mostly irrelevant since the webserver writes the file, anyone using it will have read/write permissions on it. 

If you do the URLs right, it's quite improbably to guess them. You can use additional restrictions, such as time available (eg 1hour after uplaod), geolocation, etc to make it harder.

Comment: okay , i thanks you for your answer , so my Solution is not Technically Possible ?